# Calculating variance for normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

A random variable is said to be normally distributed with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, if its density function is given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\;\;-\infty<x<\infty$$.

Now I need find the variance of the normal distribution i.e. the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2f(x)dx$$.

Now to prove we use the fact that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}=\sqrt\pi.$$ I have proved the above identity using multivariable calculus, double integration, and polar coordinates.

So now I consider $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}(x-\mu)^2e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$=$\lim_{R\longrightarrow  \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-R}^{R}(x-\mu)^2e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx $. Now I use substitution and take $y=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. So I get $\lim_{R\longrightarrow  \infty}\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}y^2e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy $.
Now I use integration by parts and get
$$\lim_{R\longrightarrow  \infty}\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left\{-e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}y\Biggr|_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}   +\int_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy\right\} .$$

My question is how do I proceed now and use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}=\sqrt\pi?$. My main issue is that I want to compute the variance using the definition of improper integral i.e. the infinite limit of definite integrals.

Comment: $e^{-y^2} y \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$

Comment: @kmitov Could you please elaborate a bit further? I get the idea but am not able to prove it rigorously. I guess this question will be helpful to many.

Comment: $\forall t>0\quad e^{-t}<\frac1{1+t}$ (because $e^t>1+t$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any real $y$ we have $$|e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}y|=\frac{|y|}{e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}}\le \frac{|y|}{1+\frac{y^2}{2}},$$ and the latter value tends to zero when $|y|$ tends to the infinity.

For any real $A<B$ we have $\int_{B}^{A} e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy=\int_{B/\sqrt{2}}^{A/\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2} e^{-x^2}dx$,
and the later value tends to $\sqrt{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$, when $A$ tends to $-\infty$ and $B$ tends to $+\infty$.

Taking into account that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ is a density function, we assume that $\sigma>0$.

The above follows that $$\lim_{R\longrightarrow  +\infty}\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(-e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}y\Biggr|_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}   +\int_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy\right)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi}=\sigma^2.$$

Comment: In the last line, how is $-e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}y\Biggr|_{\frac{-R-\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{R-\mu}{\sigma}}$ zero?

Comment: @user534666 When $R$ tends to $+\infty$ then both $\left|\tfrac{R+\mu}{\sigma}\right|$ and $\left|\tfrac{-R+\mu}{\sigma}\right|$ tend to $+\infty$, so the required conclusion follows from the first sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mu=0,\sigma=1$ the integral is symmetric around zero:
$$2\int_0^\infty x^2\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx\stackrel{t=x^2/2}{=}4\int_0^\infty t \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{2\pi }}(2 t)^{-1/2}dt=2\int_0^\infty t^{1/2}\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{\pi}}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(3/2)=1$$
Since $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ we have $X\sim \mu+\sigma Z$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. We conclude.